Can't find admin_client_secret in KeyCloak
I am trying to configure locally Keycloak server and FastAPI application.
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.11
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8280:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Then I created
realm -- "demo" and client -- "backend"
Then created a FastAPI app
I don't know where to find admin_client_secret in KeyCloak
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

from fastapi_keycloak import FastAPIKeycloak, OIDCUser

app = FastAPI()
idp = FastAPIKeycloak(
    server_url="http://localhost:8280/auth",
    client_id="backend",
    client_secret="FLeziJtRu2h7fbaSBUs2OME1Lpj3qmWZ",
    admin_client_secret="admin_password_here",
    realm="demo",
    callback_uri="http://localhost:8089/callback"
)
idp.add_swagger_config(app)

@app.get("/admin")
def admin(user: OIDCUser = Depends(idp.get_current_user(required_roles=["admin"]))):
    return f'Hi premium user {user}'


@app.get("/user/roles")
def user_roles(user: OIDCUser = Depends(idp.get_current_user)):
    return f'{user.roles}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('app:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=8089)

I have an error
File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_keycloak/api.py", line 165, in __init__
    self._get_admin_token()  # Requests an admin access token on startup
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_keycloak/api.py", line 349, in _get_admin_token
    response = requests.post(url=self.token_uri, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 575, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 368, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/32_keylock_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 439, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://None?

